# Formula Query on PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My input data is like this

```
wavelength   reflectance
341.6        1.15  
343.1        1.14
344.7        1.13
346.3        1.14
347.9        1.14
349.5        1.12
351.1        1.12
352.6        1.13
354.2        1.13
```

I am using this formula Query

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(    
        PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS INT)
                     -CAST(wavelength AS INT)%5
        ORDER BY wavelength) AS ROW_ID,
      wavelength,
      avg( reflectance ) OVER(
        PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS INT)
                     -CAST(wavelength AS INT)%5
        ORDER BY wavelength
        rows BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING
             and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) As reflectance 
      FROM 
      test
    )
    select trunc(wavelength/5)*5 AS wavelengthwavelength, reflectance
    from CTE
    where row_id = 1
```

In this query it povides the output like this

```
wavelength  reflectance
340         2.6400000000000000
340         2.5200000000000000
345         2.5200000000000000
355         2.5500000000000000
360         2.4250000000000000
365         2.4650000000000000
365         2.5450000000000000
370         2.4733333333333333
380         2.6600000000000000
385         2.7400000000000000
390         2.7700000000000000
390         2.8833333333333333
```

In this output 340,365,390 is placed as twice, instead of placed as twice it should be placed as once only based on the min value, how should do this...

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS(
   SELECT row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY wavelength::int - wavelength::int%5
                            ORDER BY wavelength) AS row_id,
          wavelength,
          avg(reflectance) OVER(PARTITION BY wavelength::int - wavelength::int%5
                           ORDER BY wavelength
                           ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING
                           AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS reflectance 
   FROM   test
   )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       trunc(wavelength/5)*5 AS wavelength, reflectance
FROM   cte
WHERE  row_id = 1
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension to standard SQL `DISITNCT` and is particularly useful if you want to add more columns and still pick the row with minimum `reflectance`. Otherwise `GROUP BY` can to the job as well.

More details in this related answer:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

With `DISTINCT ON`, you *need* `ORDER BY` in the final `SELECT`. However, you will want to add that either way. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW)

> Currently, window functions always require presorted data, and so the
>   query output will be ordered according to one or another of the window
>   functions' `PARTITION BY`/`ORDER BY` clauses. It is not recommended to
>   rely on this, however. Use an explicit top-level `ORDER BY` clause if
>   you want to be sure the results are sorted in a particular way.

Comment: If i am giving 5 instead of 10 placed in the query, it is giving same interval as two times, i want to omit the rows that are having same wavelength interval,but it is omitting rows340;1.1375 360;1.168 380;1.302 390;1.405 400;1.456 410;1.53666666666667 420;1.606 430;1.75333333333333 440;1.874 460;2.124 480;2.34 490;2.47 510;2.91833333333333 520;3.19 530;3.404 550;3.90166666666667 560;4.09333333333333 570;4.24833333333333 580;4.356 590;4.475 600;4.43333333333333 610;4.43 620;4.46166666666667 630;4.55333333333333 640;4.53428571428571

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is that you use `trunc(wavelength)` exchange of `trunc(wavelength/5)*5` but if you don't want to do that you can do something like this:

```
select trunc(trunc(wavelength * 5) / 5) AS wavelengthwavelength, reflectance
from CTE
where row_id = 1
```

Comment: It is giving the same output i shown above, i want to filter the output as for one wavelength there is one reflectance based on the selection of min wavelength value

Answer (score 0):

```
select wavelength, MIN(reflectance) 
FROM (select trunc(wavelength/5)*5 AS wavelength, reflectance
    from CTE
    where row_id = 1) src
GROUP BY wavelength
```

Comment: It is changing the output value differently, not based on wavelength order